# Processed file sizes for Build exceed the 100 MB app file limit

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, ios9

I'm seeing an issue after submission to the app store with Xcode 7 and iOS 9.

My app's always been ~70MB after submission, and the exported IPA of the latest build is sitting at 67MB. After submission to iTunes connect, I'm getting a warning next to the build number saying that the processed file size exceeds 100 MB. I'm not using bitcode and I can't think of anything on my end that would affect the size of the submission now.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Does the warning match what is displayed on the Build Details page? (click on the build number)

After upload, some processing is performed that can change the size of the final package (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW7), but an increase like that looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Yeah, i'm seeing the warning on the build details page as well.